# Check performance of web api post request

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way to check the performance of a post request with different bandwidth?

Actually I am posting a file to restful api. I want to check the time taken with different bandwidths say 100 mbps,5 mbps. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more precise?

Comment: i have a restful web api that stores the json into database. I need to check the time taken for the post request with different bandwidths more like a performance test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the most automated way for tests, but if you're doing posts from your browser (e.g. asp.net website), you could use browser throttling feature to manipulate that kind of data. You would also see then how much time does it take.

For instance, in Chrome, when you open Developer Tools (F12), in the network tab you can find a dropdown for that. 'No throttling' is selected by default. You can change it to simulate certain bandwith.

[image: Chrome Throttling]

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use tools available and I would refer JMeter for your purpose.
These links might give you insight on that :

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test

https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/Controlling%20Bandwidth%20in%20JMeter%20to%20simulate%20different%20networks